Lookback option with floating strike: gamma explanation
Suppose we have a lookback call option with a floating strike (you can buy at the minimum reached price).
I do not understand why its gamma should be constant above then strike price. Since above the minumum the LB option should behave like a vanilla call, I would expect its gamma to go to zero. The picture is taken from Dynamic Hedging by N. Taleb (pag. 405).
Does this means that delta simply increase linearly of an amount related to the constant gamma? If so, any intuition why is it so?

Please, let me know if more details are needed. Thanks for the help.
Edit
I guess that the author could mean that, supposing the chart is representing a lookback put that allows the buyer to sell the maximum, the gamma is constant since if the highest price will be above the current strike, this latter will be updated consequently (ceteris paribus). Do you agree with this possible interpretation?

I don't think a flat gamma ITM makes sense at all. This would mean that delta increases linearly (and never tapers off), which makes the lookback call payoff increase exponentially ITM, which it does not. Maybe take another look at the text?

Thanks for your point of view. I looked in the text (the PO was posted 2 month ago) but I did not find anything useful to understand that.
